# Change elseif to else statement

Tags: powershell

I'm new to PowerShell and had some feedback from a lecturer at school.

Consider this simple code:

```
if (!(Test-Path -Path $installDirectory)) {
    Write-Output "Creating directory $installDirectory"
    New-Item -Path $installDirectory -ItemType Directory
}

elseif (Test-Path -Path $installDirectory) {
     Write-Output "Directory $installDirectory already exists."
}
```

The lecturer said the `elseif` should be changed for an `else` to improve my code.

Is this correct?

```
else { 
    Write-Output "Directory $installDirectory already exists."
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not try and run it?

Comment: You will need `elseif` if you have more than two conditions to test. In case of  `Test-Path`, you have only two outcomes, either the path exists or it does not. `Else` should be fine here.

Comment: If your pattern is `if (a) {...} elseif (!a) { ... }` then yes, your code can be improved by removing the second if. If there is a chance that the expression will magically flip state between the two (ie. you're checking two random values), then no, it won't be improved but in this case it will. Your lecturer is right although he probably should've told you why, not just "do it". **Make it a habit of questioning advice, not "I'm not sure that is correct", instead ask "why is that correct?"** and in this case you should've asked your lecturer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The states checked by your `if` and `elseif` conditions are mutually exclusive. Either the directory `$installDirectory` exists, or it doesn't. Hence there's no need to check twice. If the condition `Test-Path -Path $installDirectory` is true, then the negated condition is automatically false.

For clarity I'd also switch your conditions, so that you avoid a negation in the `if` condition.

```
if (Test-Path -Path $installDirectory) {
    Write-Output "Directory $installDirectory already exists."
} else {
    Write-Output "Creating directory $installDirectory"
    New-Item -Path $installDirectory -ItemType Directory
}
```